# how to create a function array with .push and .unshift in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble with this simple checkpoint question for my program at Bloc.io in JavaScript. I am up to .push and .unshift in Arrays. Here is the exercise:

Create a function named addTwo. This function should:

- take one argument, an array
- return the array with a 1 added to the start and end of the original array

How do I do this? So far all I have is: function addTwo(argument) { }

Thanks!

Comment: What's your approach so far?

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's very hard to answer this question without simply giving you the complete answer, which doesn't feel fair as it won't help you learn. Here's the best hint I have: The assignment has already told you EXACTLY what to do in plain english, those instructions just need to be translated into code. What you have so far is a good start, now how do you plan to use `push` and `unshift`, and what value do you want to `return` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you should do. Push and unshift can't be chained together and you need to do as a couple of statements to achieve what you are looking for.

```js
function addTwo(inputArray) {
  //append at the end.
  inputArray.push(1);
  //append to the begining
  inputArray.unshift(1);
  return inputArray;
}
var inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
inputArray = addTwo(inputArray);
console.log(inputArray);
```